# To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Check for non Matching Data of Integration Services or higher

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run a Test package created using SSDT BIT for Visual Studio 2012. This package is ran from a Windows Forms application created in Visual Studio 2012 but i get the error message "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Check for non Matching Data of Integration Services or higher.
" 
Please Note
I have SSDT and Intergration Services installed in SQL Server 2012.

Initially the package executed successfully, it only consisted of an OLEDB Source and an OLEDB Destination. I started getting the error after adding a lookup which checks for non matching data.

Answer (score 0):

were are you running this Forms application, on your machine or from a different machine than yours?

how is the application calling the package? you probably have a reference issue that you need to figure out. i assume if you were to execute the package from the command line, it will produce the same error.

add an explicit reference in your package to the "lookup transformation" dll, and see if that helps.